# Allow a script to execute inside cms

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a site setup and working well based in Silverstripe cms. I created a php script (not a plugin) that does some file conversion. I uploaded the script to the site root, and created an .htaccess inside it with "Allow from all", and I give 777 to folder permission in order to allow access to this script from a browser. However, the site's "page not found" page shows up instead.

Can someone explain what I'm missing here?
this is some conditionals in htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.gif)|(\.jpg)|(\.png)|(\.css)|(\.js)|(\.php)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* sapphire/main.php?url=%1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

here is the current htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks 
### SILVERSTRIPE START ### 
<IfModule mod_dir.c> DirectorySlash Off </IfModule> 
RewriteEngine On RewriteBase / RewriteRule ^index.html$ http://www.domain.com/ [R=301,L] RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.gif)|(\.jpg)|(\.png)|(\.css)|(\.js)|(\.php)$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/csv_compare 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule .* sapphire/main.php?url=%1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L] 
### SILVERSTRIPE END ###
```

Comment: Can you post any rules that your CMS put in htaccess?

Comment: just updated the post with some rules, thanks

Comment: And when you comment out the rules, you still get a 404 error? Are you sure the php file is accessable? (it doesn't need to be 777, just 644)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Silverstripe, but it sounds like the root htaccess might be redirecting. However, the safety of allow from all/777 is a little risky!

Edit: Looking at the htaccess at https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-installer/blob/master/.htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

That is telling the system to redirect to the framework if the request is not for a valid file. If you are requested a directory, that might be the problem. You could add the following before the line above:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Comment: I want to allow just the script folder not all. Where can I add the folder name?

Comment: Try something like: 'RewriteRule ^(admin|user)($|/) - [L]', where admin|user is the folders you want access to. This rule basically stops the rules from continuing if its matched, so put it before the rest.

Comment: the root one. its basically saying if the folder is named admin or user, don't process any more rules (so in your case don't redirect through framework).

Comment: ok, I added this above all rules in the root .htaccesss file: 
RewriteRule ^(csv_compare)($|/) - [L]
Now I can see the folder files, but when i click on index.html to run the script it redirects to the root domain..

Comment: Ah right, you'd be better adding 'RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/csv_compare' before the 'RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f'

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure, adding 'RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/yourDirectoryName' should work! What's your htaccess look like now?

Comment: like this:
`Options +FollowSymlinks
### SILVERSTRIPE START ###
<IfModule mod_dir.c>
DirectorySlash Off
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.html$          http://www.domain.com/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.gif)|(\.jpg)|(\.png)|(\.css)|(\.js)|(\.php)$ 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/csv_compare
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* sapphire/main.php?url=%1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
### SILVERSTRIPE END ###`

Comment: Bit hard to read, but first thing I noticed is you have RewriteRule ^index.html$ http://www.maponics.com/ [R=301,L]. That would redirect any index.html to maponics.com

Comment: is there a way to make my script an exception to the rule above?

Comment: You'd have to add 'RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/yourDirectoryName' before that line to

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17901/discussion-between-lecca-and-kumo99)

Comment: Thank you so much.. after moving that rule about, it is working now :)